# How to play 16-bit pcm array programmatically

Tags: c#, audio, pcm

I have a short[] array filled with 16-bit pcm values.

I want to be able to play it without adding any header, and without saving any files to my memory.

I know that I might need a class that gives parameters like bit rate and stuff like that  - but I want to do it all in my program without and files.

I am working in C#.

Thanks ahead,
Ofek

Comment: Could you show us the code that you've created so far?

Comment: thanks for your answer. there is not a lot show.. I basically have a short array filled with 16-bit pcm values - and I want to be able to play it/stop it/pause it programmatically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install [CSCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CSCore/) through nuget. 
Then write all your shorts into a memorystream (you can use the binarywriter to do that).
After that use the CSCore.Codecs.RAW.RawDataReader to create an audiosource from your memorystream by specifing the format (16 bit, pcm, samplerate, channelcount). 
After that you can use for example the CSCore.SoundOut.WasapiOut class to playback the stream. 
You can take a look at the little sample on codeplex (bottom of the page). http://cscore.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thnaks man it worked! now I need a way to play it in Real-Time. meaning that instead of converting the array to a memorystream and put it in the RawDataReader, I want to create some sort of connection between the RawDataReader and the array of the pcm and the array will keep getting longer and longer while the RawDataReader is playing the pcm that is already in the array.. kinda complicated. any ideas?

Comment: you could use the WriteableBufferingSource instead. http://cscore.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#CSCore/Streams/WriteableBufferingSource.cs

That will overwrite the memory after some time. Don't forget to set FillWithZeros to false.