# playing array filled with pcm values in real time

Tags: c#, audio, real-time, pcm

I need to be able to play a short[] array filled with 16-bit PCM values (after decode) in real time.
The array keeps getting longer and the player should be able to play it while the array is "growing".

I an writing in C#.

thanks ahead,
Ofek

**EDIT:**
I used the BufferedWaveProvider and the code looks like this:

```
Class Player
{
    Private WaveFormat waveForamt=new WaveFormat(8000,16,1);
    private BufferedWaveProvider bufferedWaveProvider;

    public Player()
    {
        bufferedWaveProvider=new BufferedWaveProvider(waveFormat);
    }

    public void AddSamples(byte[] array)
    {
        bufferedWaveProvider.AddSamples(array,0,array.length);
        WaveOut waveout=new WaveOut();
        waveout.Init(bufferedWaveProvider);
        waveout.Play();
    }
}
```

the array that the AddSamples func gets is 32000 long I can see the parameters
    bufferedWaveProvider.BufferedBytes = 32000
    bufferedWaveProvider.BufferedBytes = 80000
    bufferedWaveProvider.BufferedDuration = 00:00:02
    bufferedWaveProvider.BufferDuration = 00:00:05

when I record the array I speak for 2 seconds and say: "one, two, three..."
The porblem is that when I play it, I just hear a quick sound, and nothing like what I said..

any ideas about what went wrong?

Thnaks, Ofek

**EDIT 2:**
Now my code looks like this, I call the AddSamples function from the Capture class. 
after each time the waveout.Play() function is called - I clear the buffer and wait for it to fill up again. once it is full again I play it, and so on. the problem is that in the second time I play the buffer the sound starts fast and then it slows down... I heard something about working with two buffers.. do you know anything about this?
Thnaks a lot! 
[image]

Here is the class that calls the player.AddSamples
[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to play 16-bit pcm array programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20310571/how-to-play-16-bit-pcm-array-programmatically)

Comment: Don't multipost. Improve your original question instead. See [ask] for details.

Comment: It's not the same question - this is about real-time playback.

Comment: It is not only almost the same question, it also shares another property: you don't show research effort and you don't provide any code to narrow conversation to specific problem.

Comment: Okay got it, I'll know for next time

Comment: Photos of the screen? I think you took "screen shot" too literally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically need to be able to set up a soundcard driver to read from an audio buffer and then write to that same buffer. The BufferedWaveProvider class in naudio could help. Take a look at http://naudio.codeplex.com/.

**Edit** : Your class works fine for me in an empty 'forms' project, playing 2 seconds of audio:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var player = new Player();

        var rand = new Random();
        var bytes = new byte[32000];
        rand.NextBytes(bytes);

        player.AddSamples(bytes);
    }
}
```

Are you calling it in a background thread, or maybe a console app? It May be a threading or callback issue - see the *1) WaveOut* section in http://naudio.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Audio%20Output%20Driver%20Selection. You may need to pass different callback options into WaveOut()?

Comment: thnaks for your answer. now its working for me, I added the callbackfunction to the WaveOut ctor. but I do have another problem if you can help me... please see my updated question once again :)

Comment: Question : Why is your player class doing anything with the WaveOut in AddSamples()? Shouldn't you just be adding samples there?

Comment: Also, is this a console app?

Comment: And finally - screenshots aren't all that friendly as they can't be copied/pasted or searched :)

Comment: I put there the waveout.Init and waveout.Play just for the test.. but I dont think it matters. no its not a console app, WPF app. and finally - I couldnt post the code for many reasons.. I could type it if it helps' I Rather not too.. :)

Comment: Okay I got it to work! all I did was putting the waveout.Init in the begining of the calss so is only happens once (sounds kinda obvious now) and it works! thnaks a lot for your help man!

Comment: Excellent. Good luck with the rest of your project! :)